# My namespace is not found in MVC 5 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im trying to create my own helpers but im totally stuck with this error. I have searched the web and read soooo many posts about this kind of issue.
When I try to add the namespace to the view I get the error "The type or namespace 'CustomHelpers' could not be found..."
So I created a class for my helper and added the namespace to the Views web.config.
My helper class

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace CustomHelpers
{
    public static class CustomHelpers
    {
        public static string Truncate(this HtmlHelper helper, string input, int length)
        {
            if (input.Length <= length)
            {
                return input;
            }
            else
            {
                return input.Substring(0, length) + "...";
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

My web.config

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="Playground.Web" />
    <add namespace="CustomHelpers"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

My View

```
@using CustomHelpers
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you should not name a class the same as its namespace.

[Do not name a class the same as its namespace](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx)

For example,

```
namespace YourProjectName.Framework
{
    public static class CustomHelpers
    {
        ...
    }
}
```